# Save XML data from DataTable encrypted

Tags: c#, xml, file, encryption, datatable

I want to save my `DataTable` in a file so that nobody can read it:

```
    private DataTable machineTable = new DataTable();
    private Rijndael crypto = Rijndael.Create();
    private FileStream stream;
    ...
    this.crypto.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
    this.crypto.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

    this.stream = new FileStream(Global.MachineParametersDataFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(this.stream, crypto.CreateEncryptor(this.crypto.Key, this.crypto.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    this.machineTable.WriteXml(stream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, true);
```

> password: 32 
>   byte IV: 16byte

My code produced a couple of binary lines, but the whole rest is completely unencrypted.

Comment: How are you storing your IV? Traditionally it is appended to the front of the crypto blob as the first 16 bytes. The IV does not need to be kept secret, it just needs to be random per encryption. Also it appears you are passing a string in as the IV, you should really be using [GenerateIV()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generateiv.aspx) to be getting that random IV each time

Comment: Lastly, if you want to protect your self from brute force attacks on the encrypted blob you should be using [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) to slow down the key generation. You can put a large enough [`IterationCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.iterationcount.aspx) that it takes 500ms to to generate the key, your end user only has to wait 500ms to use your program, a attacker has to wait 500ms per guess of the password (re-use the IV as the salt for the function)

Answer (score 3):

You're writing to the stream not the cryptoStream.
`this.machineTable.WriteXml(cryptoStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, true);`